# `text_field_tag`'s second argument

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In [RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/270-authentication-in-rails-3-1?view=asciicast) there is a

```
<%= text_field_tag :email, params[:email] %>
```

And this code outputs following html.

```
<input id="email" name="email" type="text">
```

Even if I delete the second argment `params[:email]`, this code outputs same html code.
I'm using rails 4 and this tutorial is with rails 3.
This is a difference between the vesions?
Or there is another reason for this `params[:email]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second argument is the text to actually place inside the text field. Let's say `params[:email] = 'email text'`, then

```
<%= text_field_tag :email, params[:email] %>
```

yields

```
<input id="email" name="email" type="text">email text</input>
```

If `params[:email] = nil` then you would get

```
<input id="email" name="email" type="text"></input>
```

The first argument is the name, the second argument the value (text in this case), and the third value is a parameter hash that contains options. Did you have a more specific question? You can view the API for v4 here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-text_field_tag